# mkString behavior with numeric range types

Tags: string, scala, range

Is there a way to make mkString work with numeric range types?

I would like to make a string such as `{1-2-3-4-5}` but for a much larger range.
mkString does not seem to produce this output when I use range definitions in the arguments. Wondering why this is the case?

```
//Desired output
@ Array(1,2,3,4,5).mkString("{","-","}") 
res860: String = "{1-2-3-4-5}"

@ Array(1 to 5).mkString("{","-","}") 
res861: String = "{Range 1 to 5}"

@ Vector('a' to 'z').mkString("{","---","}") 
res856: String = "{NumericRange a to z}"
```

Comment: just found a way to do this using .tabulate - Array.tabulate(20)(x =>x).mkString("{","-","}")

Comment: Are you want `Array(1 to 5: _*).mkString("{","-","}")` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mkString()` works correctly on a `Range`. No intermediate `Array` needed.

```
Range(3, 23, 4).mkString("{","-","}") //res0: String = {3-7-11-15-19}
('b' to 'w' by 3).mkString(":")      //res1: String = b:e:h:k:n:q:t:w
```

The reason `Array(1 to 5).mkString(...)` doesn't work is because you've created an `Array` of a single element: the `Range` itself. You've created an array of ranges. No wonder the `mkString()` output isn't what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need `Array(1 to 5: _*)` or `Array.range(1, 6)`, be careful with the type:

```
scala> Array(1 to 5)
res2: Array[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive] = Array(Range 1 to 5)

scala> Array(1 to 5: _*)
res3: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> Array.range(1, 6)
res4: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```